# mysql take different execution time

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT user.name, user.age, user.lastlogin, user.loguserid,user.sex, ( 3963.17 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 54.662280100000) ) * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( -1.630407900000) - RADIANS( longitude ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 54.662280100000 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance_in_miles
FROM user
WHERE latitude != '' 
AND longitude != ''
AND loguserid !=526306 
AND age >18 AND age <=50 
AND  sex !=0
AND ( 3963.17 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 54.662280100000 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) * COS( RADIANS( -1.630407900000 ) - RADIANS( longitude ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 54.662280100000) ) * SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) ) ) <=50 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT blockuser.userid
FROM blockuser 
WHERE blockuser.newuserid = user.loguserid 
AND blockuser.userid =526306 AND siteid =1071) 
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT fav.userid FROM fav WHERE fav.favuserid =user.loguserid
AND siteid =1071 AND fav.userid =526306 ) ORDER BY `user`.`loguserid` DESC
```

Here is my sql?it always show different time of execution?any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

MySql has a query cache. If the same statement is executed a second time, usually this takes only part of the time compared to the first execution, since the result can e taken from the query cache.

Once the cache has been invalidated / purged, it will again need a bit more time to execute.

Depending on what other clients on the database are doing, probably this statement waits for a release of a table lock which is needed for the sub-queries etc. There are precedences in the locks for `SELECT`, `INSERT` and `UPDATE` which probably apply.

Comment: please update my query if it  required change .why it showing different execution time.i need constant time to execute this

Comment: "constant time" is not achievable on a DBS like mysql. You may add `"SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...` to your queries if this feature is enabled in the mysql config, see here: [mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/query-cache-in-select.html)

Comment: Adding this SQL_no_CACHE would effect  my php file in which this queries has been effected?

Comment: This will again showing different execution time...SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE user.name

Comment: Which part of "..."constant time" is not achievable on a DBS like mysql..." is unclear?

Comment: I mean to say my query will take execute in same time.for now it will take variation in time

Comment: On a multi-user, multi-tasking system with hyperthreading etc. etc. and a DBMS like mysql this **is not achievable**. Take it or leave it.